# Syntax Error while trying to use Cythons memoryviews

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, cython, typed-memory-views

I'm following [this guide on memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html).

But when I tried the code in the Quickstart section on Jupyter, it gave this error:

[image]

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-33f3a8b46ca3>", line 3
cdef int [:, :, :] narr_view = narr
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't even know how to search for this error since it's syntax related but this syntax is recommended by Cython.org. I think it may be because I'm using this code in the wrong place (not on Jupyter platform).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: All cython codes should be in the `%%cython` cell.   `%%cython` is a cell magick. `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` says it's not python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each cell is executed by itself, so you need to use `%%cython` in every cell that should be compiled with cython. You even need to `import numpy` in every of these cells.

Use:

```
%%cython

import numpy as np
narr = ...

cdef int[:, :, :] narr_view = narr
```